# How to fetch data in table group by other column in PHP

Tags: php

I have a record like this in database:

```
section_id    description    level_id
1             Amethyst       1
2             Betelguise     1
3             Daisy          2
4             Rose           2
```

I want it to display in my php table just like this:

```
Level 1      
Amethyst     
Betelguise   

Level 2
Daisy
Rose
```

Can anyone please help me? I am new at this.
Here's my code:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Descriptions</th>
<th>Level</th>
</tr>
</thead>
                <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_sectiontaken"; ?>
                <?php $result = $db->query($sql); ?>
                <?php if ($result->num_rows > 0) { ?>
                    <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                        <?php $id = $row['section_id'];
                        $desc = $row['description'];
                        $gr = $row['level_id']; ?>
 <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-transform:capitalized;">
                    <?php echo $desc; ?>
                </td>
                <td style="text-transform:capitalized;">
                    <?php echo $gr; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But it gives me this result in table:

```
Descriptions    Level
Amethyst        1
Betelguise      1
Daisy           2
Rose            2
```

Comment: Are those levels fixed?

Comment: The levels can be added too. Example if there is 3 in the level_id then the table must have Level 3 in its headers

Comment: I've done searches about this and some results says that I must make it on a loop but I dont know how

Comment: @MarkC what version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group_concat function for this. Use below code if suits your requirements

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT level_id,GROUP_CONCAT(description) AS description FROM series group by level_id"; ?>
<?php $result = $db->query($sql); ?>
<?php if ($result->num_rows > 0) { ?>
    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <?php
        $id = $row['section_id'];
        $desc = $row['description'];
        $gr = $row['level_id'];
        $leveArr[$gr][] = $desc;// Create an array with level and description
    }  } ?>
</tbody>

<table>
    <tr><!-- header-->
        <?php foreach ($leveArr as $key => $value) { ?>
            <td><?php echo "LEVEL " . $key ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($leveArr as $key => $value) { 
            foreach ($value as $key_1 => $data) { ?>
                <td><?php
                $data = explode(",", $data);

                foreach ($data as $key_2 => $final) {
                    echo $final . "<br>";
                }
                ?></td>
                <?php }


             } ?>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

[Check the sandbox example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8877a061cbbafd18fd492a90adee72beea5a5efc)

Change query with `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(if (description ='', null, description)) as description,count(description) as heigher,level_id FROM yourtablename WHERE 1 GROUP BY level_id
```

And After.They return array like this

```
$arr=[['description'=>'a,b,c,d','level_id'=>'1','heigher'=>'4'],['description'=>'a,b,c,d','level_id'=>'2','heigher'=>'4']]; ?>
```

Then Finally Create Table as like this

```
$sql="SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(if (description ='', null, description)) as description,count(description) as heigher,level_id FROM yourtablename WHERE 1 GROUP BY level_id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
   $arr =[];
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       $arr[]=$row;
     }
    }
        <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <?php foreach ($arr as $key => $value): ?>
            <th><?='level'.$value['level_id']?></th>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
           $arr = array_filter($arr,function($a=[]){
             return $a['level_id'] != 0
            }) //filter level not a zero
        $h = max(array_map(function($a=[]){
          return $a['heigher']; //filter array['heigher only']
        },$arr)); // its get the heighest length of description value like [10,15,100]=>100
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
           $value['description'] = !empty($value['description']) ?explode(',',$value['description']):'';
           $arr[$key]=$value;
         }
         ?>
          <?php for ($i=0; $i < $h[0]; $i++) {?>
            <tr>
              <?php foreach ($arr as $key => $value): ?>
                <th><?=isset($value['description'][$i])? $value['description'][$i] :''?></th>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php }?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: It works sir and Im very glad. But there is Level 0 showing in the table how can I get rid of it?